# Flutter audioplayers package can't play audio inside workmanager's executeTask function-background task

Tags: flutter, dart, android-workmanager, flutter-audioplayers

I am trying to implement an alarm functionality in my Flutter app.I wanna schedule the alarm using flutter ***workmanager*** package so that the alarm can be played in background even the app is closed.
I was trying to play audio using the ***audioplayers*** package.

Normally,the audio is playing while not using it inside the workmanager executeTask function.The workmanager is working though.I've tested with print statement.But the audio is not playing.Here is the code of my main.dart file

**main.dart file**

```
import 'package:early_bird/functions/audio.dart';
import 'package:early_bird/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> callBack() async {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    try {
      Audio audio = Audio('audio/sound.mp3');
      print('I am running');
      await audio.play();
      return Future.value(true);
    } catch (err) {
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  });
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Workmanager().initialize(callBack, isInDebugMode: true);
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        HomeScreen.routeName: (_) => HomeScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I've configure the audio inside the audio.dart file and call the Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask() function on a button click.

How can I solve it now?